# How to view contents of a vector while debugging in Code Blocks?

Tags: codeblocks

I use Code::Blocks with a simple application. I have a vector a that contains three integers, {1, 2, 3}. I added the "a" variable to watch, but I can't see its content. In the watch, I right click on a and select properties and check the box "Watch as array". I also clicked on Update. The program is stopped after the vector is initialized with the values. I also removed the variable from watch and added it again. Is there a way to see the content of a?
I already checked the answers to the almost identical question "How to view contents of an array while debugging in Code Blocks?" and it did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer which provided a working solution: http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php/topic,22325.msg151987.html#msg151987

I downloaded "TDM-GCC MinGW Compiler" from https://sourceforge.net/projects/tdm-gcc/?source=typ_redirect and I selected it as debugger in Code::Blocks.

Answer (score 6):

Turning off this option works for me :

```
- Settings -> Debugger... -> GDB/CDB Debugger -> Default -> Disable startup scripts (-nx) (GDB only) -> Set to "off"
```

Comment: I also solved this problem by unchecking the option "Disable startup scripts (-nx)"